# Copying a remote file from Linux to a local server using scp

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, scp

So, I'm attempting to simply transfer a unix file (demo) from a server to my local computer via ssh and scp. In Putty, I'm using the command as follows:

```
scp hasanjee@cs.utm.utoronto.ca:~/A1/demo \desktop
```

this works and even downloads:

```
demo                                                                                                                              100% 4096   885.9KB/s   00:00
```

I've tried multiple directories:

```
scp hasanjee@cs.utm.utoronto.ca:~/A1/demo \desktop\demo
```

What am I missing here? Any ideas? I am using Windows 10

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking questions like this on [su]. When you do, you should explain in more detail the actual problem you're having, because you haven't really described a problem here.

Answer (score 0):

maybe try adding a full path...

```
scp -P 22 hasanjee@cs.utm.utoronto.ca:~/A1/demo/somefile C:\Users\{username}\Desktop\
```

-p: portnumber